# Convert bytes array into string

Tags: java

I need a way to decode them all, thats it
I have searched the internet and all ive found is converting string into bytes array, can anyone please provide me with java code can do the job
I have found this class which convert but i need to reverse it

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String example = "executiondate 16/12/201";
    byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();
    String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Text : " + example);
    System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
    System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + doc2.toString());

    String s = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + s);
}
```

I'm not a school student stealing from others I said that I searched the internet also I said I'm not a java developer, the thing is i have a blocking issue requires me to decode some values and these values are in this format:

```
[B@3b280492
```

Comment: This code DOES convert a byte array into a string. `String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`

Comment: i cant reverse the class to enter byte array to convert to string, forgive my poor java knowledge but can you help me.
i need to enter byte array and the return is string.

Comment: You aren't listening. This line: `String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");` does what you want. Just place it in its own function, which returns the string.

Comment: "but i need to reverse it" if you mean reverse string back to bytes then you can just use `yourString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. BTW if that is not what you wanted try [edit]ing your question and add more details like example of your input data and what output you would expect for it (preferably with explanation of why such output should be expected). BTW2: `[B@3b280492` doesn't represent content of byte array, but its *type@hexHashCode*.

Comment: you mean like this
String doc2 = new String("[B@3b280492", "UTF-8");

Comment: i apologize for my poor knowledge in java, but Pshemo said its a hexHashCode, i couldn't manage to decode it and honestly i have no idea where to place the codes that you kindly have posted to help me, these codes i need to decode if anybody can hint me how to or where to decode them ill be very thankful.

Comment: So its a dead end for me to convert this value into string back

Comment: Maybe you should add the code where you want to use this, and we can help you further, since you can't seem to understand what we are saying.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `String doc2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");` from your code already does what you want. You can place it in a function if you want to.

```
public String convertBytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```